# Google App script doPost doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying code a BMI HTML web by Google app script. However, the result always didn't appear by doPost.
My code is below :

Code.gs

```
function doPost(e){

 var h= e.parameter.h;
 var w = e.parameter.w;
 return 
HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("bmi="+w/((h*h)/10000));
}

function doGet(e)
{

var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
t.serviceUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
return t.evaluate();

}
```

Index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="bmiForm" action="<?= serviceUrl ?>" method="post">
 <div>height(cm): <input type="text" name="h"/></div>
 <div>weight(kg): <input type="text" name="w"/></div>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Look for Answer

Comment: Can you verify your event handler is getting called? Use `console` and send a log to Stackdriver (regular `Logger` will not be dependable for webapp situations)

Comment: If you are not familiar with the `google.script.run.function()` client side API, you might want to look at that.  If you are using an Apps Script Web App, sidebar, or dialog box then that might be a better option.  [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)  If your HTML form is not an Apps Script Web App, that is different.  If that's the case, then let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Identified the error this script threw in the browser console -

> Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/a/exotel.in/macros/s/WhateverScriptID/exec' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

## Solution

Adding `.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)` while returning `doPost`'s HTML output.

Refer **Class HtmlOutput** > [setXFrameOptionsMode(mode)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output.html#setxframeoptionsmodemode).

### Code.gs

```
function doPost(e) {
  var h= e.parameter.h;
  var w = e.parameter.w;
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("bmi="+w/((h*h)/10000)).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function doGet(e) {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  t.serviceUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

### Index.html

This remains the same -

```
<html>

<body>
    <form id="bmiForm" action="<?= serviceUrl ?>" method="post">
        <div>height(cm):
            <input type="text" name="h" />
        </div>
        <div>weight(kg):
            <input type="text" name="w" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This will display the desired results.